# XAMPP -> Apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, httpd.conf

I returned the port to 80 from 8080 and now the apache is not starting. I reverted all of the things that needs to be back like 80 and 443.

```
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:53:41 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

And i already disabled iis as well.

Comment: Do what it says, look at the logs and find out what's wrong...

Comment: 1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
    1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
    1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
    1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
    1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
   1:02:30 PM  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...                                     But I already closed iis and skype. Is sqlserver affects this as well?

Comment: Possibly. You can check for running services. Here's a good post on windows: [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: Try this..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhEnuOggnCM&t=2s

Answer (score 0):

Please confirmed that in your machine skype is installed or not.
if it is installed then change port of skype. due to port conflicted apache might not be starting.

Comment: I already unchecked that thing in the connection tab in advanced setting in skype and it was closed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

i change port in httpd.conf to 8080 and use this url:http://localhost:8080/ and it work correct.

for change port change listen.

-------------------------------------------- httpd.conf --

Listen 8080

Comment: 8080 is working properly but because of some consequences in our project we need to go back to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

> The following worked for me

> Select "Run as administrator"

[image]

> Click on the left checkbutton next to Apache

[image]

> And finally Uninstall Apache
>
> And in my case that worked! And I tried a lot of different options